# How to check for a letter in raw_input

Tags: python

I want the script to check if the user inputted the letter "b" at the beginning of his input

here is my code:

```
word = raw_input("Enter the magic word:");
print "your magic word is %s" % (word);
```

if he didn't enter the letter "b" at the beginning, the script will automatically add it.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to add semicolon in Python

```
word = raw_input("Enter the magic word:")
word = word if word.startswith('b') else 'b' + word
print "your magic word is %s" % (word)
```

Comment: You may have the logic flipped.

Answer (score 2):

I am not telling you how to finish your checking but you should use startswith:

```
>>> if word.startswith('b'):
...     print "Hei"
... else:
...     print "No"
```